# Codeigniter - php cli see only __construct function

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
class Programmatic extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo '__construct'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function tester()
    {
        echo 'tester';
    }

}
```

This is my sample class in CI.
When I run php by command line:

```
php /my_path/index.php programmatic tester
```

the result on my screen is only:

> __construct

I've tried to input wrong function name, e.g. tester2 and CI give me an error:

> ERROR: Not Found, The controller/method pair you requested was not found.

Why I didn't see "tester" on my screen when I run my command? Any idea?

**// EDIT - I find problem**
It was problem with my hooks - I have redirect to SSL (https). Now I have one exception - if it is cli_request it didn't redirect to https.

Comment: If your using codeigniter 3 check your filename also has first letter uppercase.

Comment: I installed new, default CI version and it works. So I think I had some problem with my CI configuration - but I don't know what is it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$ cd /Users/MyUsername/Sites/code

php index.php controler method
```

or

```
 php index.php/controller/function/param1/
```

Comment: Didn't work properly: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CI_Controller' not found.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Run > "cmd"` in Windows and navigate to Your CodeIgniter project.

`$ cd /path/to/project;`  -> you need to change and go to this project folder.

`$ php index.php programmatic tester`

If you did it right, you should see

> Result:
>  __construct
>       tester

Reference Link: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html
Regards:

Comment: Your link is out of date. Ellislab does not deal with codeigniter any more please update links from here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs you will find the user guide for ci2 and ci3